# Finding Probability of on arrangement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In a box, there are $100$ tickets numbered $1,\cdots, 100$. Let five tickets are taken out randomly one by one and kept in same order. Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,x_5$  be the numbers on the tickets $1,2,3,4,5$ respectively. Find the probability 
$$ a) P(x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5)?$$ 
$$ b) P(x_1<x_2<x_3>x_4>x_5)? $$
I am facing hard time solving this problem. If anyone helps that is well appreciated.

Comment: Hint for the first one:  any order of the five is as probable as any other.

Comment: Note:  that hint works for the second part as well, though you do need to work a little harder in that case.

Comment: Sorry. I am not successful to go further with the hint. Could you please help me with a little bit more information?

Comment: More detail for the first hint:  how many possible orders are there?  Since the orders are equi-probable, if there are $k$ orders the probability of seeing one particular order is $\frac 1k$.  For instance, if you had $2$ cards instead of $5$ we'd instantly have $P(x_1<x_2)=\frac 12$.

Comment: For (1), it's $1/5!.$

Comment: Thank you guys. Your suggestions have been useful to me. I've been able to solve the problem on my own using them.